# jQuery: toggleClass, multiple <td>-elements, only one highlighted

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, onclick, toggleclass

**HTML**

```
<table cellpadding=10>
  <tr>
    <td id="g1" class="tdback">test 1</td>
    <td>
      <button onclick="clickHighlightTd(g1);">click</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="g2" class="tdback">test 2</td>
    <td>
      <button onclick="clickHighlightTd(g2);">click</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="g3" class="tdback">test 3</td>
    <td>
      <button onclick="clickHighlightTd(g3);">click</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="g4" class="tdback">test 4</td>
    <td>
      <button onclick="clickHighlightTd(g4);">click</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

**CSS**

```
.tdback {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.tdhighlight {
  background-color: #999999;
}
```

---

**JS**

```
function clickHighlightTd(str) {
  $(str).toggleClass('tdhighlight');
}
```

---

I want to click on a button, the td in the same line should toggle the class to ".tdhighlight" and when clicking on any other button, the previous (or all other td) should get the standard class (".tdback") and the td in this line should get highlighted.

Here is a **JSFiddle**. Unfortunately the code works on my site, but not in **JSFiddle**. Maybe I have missed something up.

Thanks for your help!

---

### **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h11pqubz/)**

---

Comment: BTW the reason your onclick function isn't running in JSFiddle is because of the way JSFiddle uses iFrames and load handlers.  To get your onclick function to run in JSFiddle scope it to the window (don't use `var`): `clickHighlightTd = function(str) {
  $(str).toggleClass('tdhighlight');
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is finally here: https://jsfiddle.net/h11pqubz/8/

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there:

```
function clickHighlightTd(str) {
  // remove class from all TD elements
  $("td").removeClass('tdhighlight');
  // your choice: use addClass/toggleClass as you prefer
  $(str).addClass('tdhighlight');
}
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h11pqubz/3/

By the way, the TDs never "lose" the class `tdback` - the other class `tdhighlight` is added additionally (that means, the TDs have both classes at the same time), and when `tdhighlight` is removed, they still have `tdback`.

Comment: $(str) wont work unless function's called with variables like "#g4"

Comment: You're right, it should not work, but I did not notice, because it worked in the fiddle.

Comment: Hm, for `$("#"+str)` to work, you would have to call `onclick="clickHighlightTd('g1');"` (note the single quotes). I must admit, I'm not entirely sure how the browser handles `g1` w/o the quotes, but it seems to pass the whole element, not just a string.

Comment: I think it results from the js script that jsFiddle uses when jQuery is lacked. I entered $("#HW_frame_cont") in jsFiddle console (main wrapper's id HW_frame_cont) which returned null whereas $("HW_frame_cont") returned the aimed element.

Comment: with # only the first td id is being addressed: https://jsfiddle.net/h11pqubz/6/

without # all td with the same id are being addressed: https://jsfiddle.net/h11pqubz/5/

working in chrome and firefox!

is there a method to change all td's in a row with #?

Comment: If you want to assign same attribute value to multiple elements, then you should use class istead of id. Id is used for unique selectors and will only match the first it finds as you encountered.

Comment: funny that it works without # with more than one id! how can i address multiple td's to change their class?

Comment: To change the class on multple elements (identified by id) you can use `$( "#g1, #g2, #g3" ).addClass(...)` - see https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Comment: But if you want to change all TDs in a TR, you should consider to add/remove the class on the TR instead (and give the TD with the button a distinct bg color of your choosing).

Comment: It doesn't work with `$( "#g1, #g2, #g3"` and multiple named IDs or with a class and `$("."+str).addClass('tdhighlight');`

Comment: Yes, it works, You need to make sure you only pass a single string to the `$()` function, as described here: https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/ - I've updated your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h11pqubz/9/ - though it seems you already moved to using a class instead of IDs, as @EmrahIzci suggested.

Answer (score 2):

You need # before selector name and you have to remove the class from all td's first

```
function clickHighlightTd(str) {
  $("td").removeClass('tdhighlight');
  $("#"+str).addClass('tdhighlight');
}
```

As alternative, remove onclick attributes and use below code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
      $("td").removeClass('tdhighlight');
      $(this).parent().find("td").addClass("tdhighlight");
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind I fixed up the code so I could get it to work but here it is:

**HTML:**

```
<table cellpadding=10>
  <tr>
    <td class="g1">test 1</td>
    <td>
      <button class="B1">click</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="g2">test 2</td>
    <td>
      <button class="B2">click</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="g3">test 3</td>
    <td>
      <button class="B3">click</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="g4">test 4</td>
    <td>
      <button Class="B4">click</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
.g1{
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.g2{
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.g3{
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.g4{
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.tdhighlight{
  background-color:#999999;
}
```

**JS/JQUERY:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.B1').click(function(){
     $('.g1').toggleClass('tdhighlight');
   $('.g2').removeClass('tdhighlight')
   $('.g3').removeClass('tdhighlight')
   $('.g4').removeClass('tdhighlight')
  });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.B2').click(function(){
     $('.g2').toggleClass('tdhighlight');
     $('.g1').removeClass('tdhighlight')
   $('.g3').removeClass('tdhighlight')
   $('.g4').removeClass('tdhighlight')
  });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.B3').click(function(){
     $('.g3').toggleClass('tdhighlight');
   $('.g1').removeClass('tdhighlight')
   $('.g2').removeClass('tdhighlight')
   $('.g4').removeClass('tdhighlight')
  });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.B4').click(function(){
     $('.g4').toggleClass('tdhighlight');
   $('.g1').removeClass('tdhighlight');
   $('.g2').removeClass('tdhighlight');
   $('.g3').removeClass('tdhighlight');
  });
});
```

**NOTE: There is probably another easier way to make it work but, given my skill and knowledge with JS/JQUERY, I found this way to make it work. I hope this helped :)**